# Child Interface's Load(x) function hides parent interface's Load() function

Tags: vb.net, inheritance, interface

I have the following generic interface

```
Public Interface IGenericDAO(Of T As {Class, IEntity})

    Sub Save(entity As T)

    Sub Delete(entity As T)

    Sub Delete(id As Long)

    Function Load(id As Long) As T

    Function Load() As List(Of T)

End Interface
```

And I'd like to have another one like this

```
Public Interface IAgendaDAO
    Inherits IGenericDAO(Of Agenda)

    Function Load(isPublished As Boolean, meetingType As MeetingType) As List(Of Agenda)

    Function Load(meetingType As Boolean) As List(Of Agenda)

End Interface
```

But in this case Compiler says that my Load functions hides my Load function without arguments
I can do such thing in C#, Why I can't in VB.NET?
What can I do to fix that? Should I name my functions each differently?

Comment: you **are** redefining `Load` in the second interface, which is OK if you just use OverLoads in the function declaration (or shadows).

Comment: Why not just declare your methods as `Overloads` like `Overloads Function Load(meetingType As Boolean) As List(Of Agenda)`? The compiler warning even suggests that.

Comment: I want to use all three Load functions. In C# this example doesn't generate any warnings or so. This is not shadowing because all methods have different signatures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, this is one of the basic choices that a language designer needs to make.  A core decision is what exactly should happen when a derived class has a member with the exact same name as a member in the base class.  This can *hide* the inherited base class member and make it difficult to use the base member.  And it is *risky*, a innocent maintenance change might suddenly no longer hide the base member and break existing code.

The C# language designers went for "hide-by-signature".  In other words, a method only hides if the base method has the exact same name **and** the exact same arguments.  This is what you are used to and hoped to happen in these interface declarations.

While other languages, like C++ and VB.NET went for "hide-by-name".  In other words, a method hides when it has the same name, regardless of what arguments it takes.  It is a "less surprises" choice, it is much easier to reason through and maintenance changes are less likely to alter behavior of existing code.

You can see this at work in this sample code:

```
Class Base
    Sub foo()
    End Sub
End Class

Class Derived
    Inherits Base

    Sub foo(i As Integer)   '' Warning: 'foo' shadows an overloadable member declared in Base
    End Sub

    Shadows Sub foo(d As Double)   '' No warning, Shadows suppresses it
    End Sub
End Class

Sub Main()
    Dim obj = New Derived
    obj.foo()          '' Error!
    Dim base As Base = obj
    base.foo()         '' Okay
End Sub
```

Do note that this is just a warning, it is not an error.  It just foreshadows the potential pain you will inflict on the client code programmer.  You can hide the warning easily, put the *Shadows* keyword in front of the Load() method.  But certainly consider avoiding the pain and suffering in the client code and just pick another name so there is never an ambiguity.